# make the darknet detector only output the label of the bounding box without confidence

Tags: python-3.x, yolo

Because of the needs of the school project, I want to make the darknet detector only output the label of the bounding box without confidence.
Because of this line of instructions:
**darknet.exe detector demo data/crosswalk.data cfg/yolov3-crosswalk.cfg_test backup/yolov3-crosswalk_last(better2).weights -i 0 -thresh 0.05 -ext_output data/1.mp4**.
So I think it should be to modify the part of demo.c, So I found a line of code for displaying thresh, the following is the code I found:

```
if (!benchmark && !dontdraw_bbox) draw_detections_cv_v3(show_img, local_dets, local_nboxes, demo_thresh, demo_names, demo_alphabet, demo_classes, demo_ext_output);
```

I deleted demo_thresh, but thresh is still displayed during the video test, please help me, thank you

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") and ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "How do I ask and answer homework questions?") pages for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Hi,@itprorh66 ,Thank you for your suggestion, I have edited the description of the problem, and I will pay more attention to it next time when I ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are using alexyAB model in your project since you have "draw_detections_cv_v3" function
go to the **image_opencv.cpp** file and find draw_detections_cv_v3 function
after that find this line:

```
sprintf(buff, " (%2.0f%%)", dets[i].prob[j] * 100);
```

and change it into :

```
sprintf(buff, "");
```

this line will append confidence into buff variable and will print in this line :

```
cv::putText(*show_img, labelstr, pt_text, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, font_size, black_color, 2 * font_size, CV_AA);
```

after changes,you should re-make darknet

Comment: Thanks for your help . But I can still see the confidence after commenting out the following line of code: 
//sprintf(buff, " (%2.0f%%)", dets[i].prob[j] * 100);

Comment: @yenmin i made some changes in answer for better understanding

Comment: @ Amir Karami   
Thank you for the method provided by the boss, although it took several days to rebuild darknet, thank you again in the end

Comment: @yenmin if it works for you then accept the answer, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @  Amir Karami 
Thank you for your reminder, I have accepted the answer.